# How to grant permission to the server to be able access php files while others cannot?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions, ubuntu-18.04

I've added this in the  `.htaccess` the file located in the root of the project:

```
<Files *.php>
    Require host lamtakam.test lamtakam.com
    Require ip ::1 95.216.xx.xx
</Files>
```

I've used `xx.xx` to keep my real ip hidden in a public community, in reality, there are numbers instead of `x`s.

Now I need to call a file daily (using a cron job `crontab`) from the same server, something like this:

```
0 22 * * * wget /path/to/file.php
```

But I get this error:

```
--2020-09-13 13:33:55--  https://lamtakam.com/path/to/file.php
Resolving lamtakam.com (lamtakam.com)... 104.31.74.192, 172.67.174.239, 104.31.75.192, ...
Connecting to lamtakam.com (lamtakam.com)|104.31.74.192|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-09-13 13:33:55 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Note: **I use Cloudflare** and these IPs belongs to it: `104.31.74.192, 172.67.174.239, 104.31.75.192`

Any idea how can I make `file.php` accessible when I can it from the same server? (And not from anywhere else)

Comment: @anubhava When I call the file directly, it throws error: `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/...`. That's why I call it as a https request.

Comment: emm .. what/how you mean exactly? @anubhava

Comment: I meant use `wget https://localhost/path/to/file.php`

Comment: @anubhava It throws `Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected. ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches requested host name ‘localhost’. To connect to localhost insecurely, use --no-check-certificate'.`

Comment: ok try this instead to get rid of this error: `curl -k https://localhost/path/to/file.php`

Comment: @anubhava Tried. `403 Forbidden`

Comment: ok add `Require ip 127.0.0.1` just below `Require host` line and/or add `localhost` in `Require host` line.

Comment: problem resolved @anubhava, thanks.. (noted that I thought `::1` can be an alternative for `127.0.0.1`, while I was wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `curl` like this in your crontab:

```
curl -k https://localhost/path/to/file.php'
```

or:

```
curl --insecure https://localhost/path/to/file.php
```

As per `man grep`:

`-k, --insecure`

> (TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate  even  for  server
> connections otherwise considered insecure.

and modify `Files` directive by allowing IP: `127.0.0.1` and host: `localhost`:

```
<Files *.php>
    Require host localhost lamtakam.test lamtakam.com
    Require ip ::1 127.0.0.1 95.216.xx.xx
</Files>
```

Comment: I wrote it this way `Require ip ::1 127.0.0.1 95.216.xx.xx` instead of having two `Require ip`s, and it looks like working. Any comment?